# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser how to get non attribute element

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

The HTML values from within the TR are:

```
<input type="radio" name="question_id[1111]" id="question_id[1111]" value="999" class="noborder" checked />Yes</div><div style="white-space:nowrap;margin-right:20px;display:inline-block;">

<input type="radio" name="question_id[1111]" id="question_id[1111]" value="888" class="noborder" />No</div>
```

My code is:

```
    $html = str_get_html($results);

    foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr)   
    {               
       foreach($tr->find('input') as $input)
       {   
          if ('not sure what to put here' == 'checked')
          {
           print $input->'value';  
          }                                 
       }
    }
```

I simply want to determine which of the results contain 'checked.' If it does, it should return 'value.' I am able to obtain the value of value using `$input->'value`' but how can I get a value of the non-element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but maybe you should try this:

```
$html = str_get_html($results);

foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr)   
{               
   foreach($tr->find('input[checked]') as $input)
   {   
       print $input->'value';                             
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Solved the problem and uses less code. thanks!